# Unable to update database from form retrieved by SELECT OPTION

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I couldn't figure out what is the problem with `$updateApproval` statement. Everything is fine and the `$_POST` is able to retrieve the data from the form. SQL statement works well on phpMyAdmin when I run it , substituting the variables so there should not be any mistakes.

Am I conflicting without knowing or there are some other reasons that my update statement is not working? Tried switching here and there but it just kept quiet and no slightest error is out. I provide you the information you need and sorry if it is tedious. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This is my database:

**Consent Table**

```
consent
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
consent_id | staff_id | approval_id | type_of_leave | consent_date_from | consent_date_to
```

**Leave Type Table**

```
leavetype
----------------------------
type_of_leave | leave_type |
```

**Staff Table**

```
 staff
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 staff_id | role_id | staff_name | gender | staff_email | password |
```

**Staff Leave table**

```
staffleave
----------------------------------------------------------------------
leave_log | staff_id | annual_leave | sick_leave .....//other leaves and so on
```

The form is over here. I have actually put a `select option` into a form, thus there's the `<td> <tr>` tag.

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="doApproval.php" method="post" name="register">
            <input hidden name="getStaffId" value="<?php echo $staffId  ?>" >               
            <input hidden name="getConsentId" value="<?php echo $consentId ?>" >            
            <input hidden name="getLeaveId" value="<?php echo $leaveId ?>" >  
                 <div class="form-group">
                       <select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="select" name="getConsentChange">
                             <option value="1" <?php if ($getCurrentStatus == 1) echo "selected"; ?>>Approve</option>
                             <option value="2" <?php if ($getCurrentStatus == 2) echo "selected"; ?>>Reject</option>
                             <option <?php if ($getCurrentStatus == 3) echo "selected"; ?>>Pending</option>
                       </select>
                 </div>
                     <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
        </form>
     </div>
</td>
```

The `POST` will be over here. The query that saves the number of days staff take works well, but not the status of their leave.

```
$staffId = $_POST['getStaffId'];
$consentId = $_POST['getConsentId'];
$getConsent = $_POST['getConsentChange'];
$getLeaveId = $_POST['getLeaveId'];

$updateApproval = "UPDATE consent SET approval_id = $getConsent WHERE consent.staff_id = '$staffId' AND consent.consent_id = $getConsent"; //Update statement that is not working

$leaveCheckpoint = "SELECT * FROM consent, staffleave, staff WHERE staffleave.staff_id = staff.staff_id 
AND staff.staff_id = consent.staff_id AND consent.consent_id = '$consentId'";

$checkpointQuery = (mysqli_query($link, $leaveCheckpoint)) or die("Retrieve checkpoint error " . mysqli_error($link));

if ($checkLeave = mysqli_fetch_array($checkpointQuery)) {
if ($checkLeave['staff_id'] = '$staffId' && $checkLeave['consent_id'] = '$consentId') {

    //retrieving the number of leaves staff have took

   if ($getLeaveId == 1 && $getConsent == 1) {
        $updatedLeave1 = $chkAnnual + $dateDiff;
        $recordLeave = "UPDATE staffleave SET annual_leave = '$updatedLeave1' WHERE staff_id = '$staffId'";
    } else if ($getLeaveId == 2 && $getConsent == 1) {
        $updatedLeave2 = $chkSick + $dateDiff;
        $recordLeave = "UPDATE staffleave SET sick_leave = '$updatedLeave2' WHERE staff_id = '$staffId'";
    } else if ......// so on when they meet the condition, it works fine and able to insert.
else {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("No data was updated in the process")
            window.location = "manageStaffLeave.php";
        </script>     
 }
<?php
   }
$successConsent = mysqli_query($link, $recordLeave) or die("Insert Leave Date Error " . mysqli_error($link));
 }

$approvalUpdate = (mysqli_query($link, $updateApproval)) or die("Update error " . mysqli_error($link));

mysqli_close($link);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
 if ($approvalUpdate && $successConsent) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "manageStaffLeave.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: `<input hidden name="getStaffId" value="<?php echo $staffId  ?>" >               
            <input hidden name="getConsentId" value="<?php echo $consentId ?>" >            
            <input hidden name="getLeaveId" value="<?php echo $leaveId ?>" >  ` Try putting ;?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out ';'

```
<input hidden name="getStaffId" value="<?php echo $staffId; ?>" > 
<input hidden name="getConsentId" value="<?php echo $consentId; ?>" > 
<input hidden name="getLeaveId" value="<?php echo $leaveId; ?>" >
```

Comment: I don't get you. The values hidden inside the form are able to `POST` over, so I don't think its the missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a basic mistake :

`$checkLeave['staff_id'] = '$staffId' && $checkLeave['consent_id'] = '$consentId`

Here you are affecting the strings `'$staffId'` to the array `$checkLeave['staff_id']` and `$consentId` to `$checkLeave['consent_id']`

Remove quote and and an equal for comparison :

`$checkLeave['staff_id'] == $staffId && $checkLeave['consent_id'] == $consentId`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Changed it, doesn't make any difference :/